# Row values as columns and group

Tags: database

I got this table with 3 rows

```
ID    Location    Value 
1     City        Phoenix
1     State       AZ
1     Country     USA
```

Need to transform this to below. Got some help to get this in 2 steps. While I am trying to get this in a single query. Any help

```
ID    City    State   Country   
1     Phoenix AZ      USA
```

I got the answer. Will post it soon.

Thanks, 
P

Comment: which rdbms????? Although note that issues of data display are generally best resolved at the application level/presentation layer if you have one (e.g. a simple PHP loop on an ordered array). And don't bother posting an answer. Just delete the question. It's neither interesting nor original.

Answer (score -1):

```
select c.Id, c.Value City, s.Value State, ct.Value Country
from tableName c
inner join tableName s on s.id = c.Id and s.Location = 'State'
inner join tableName ct on ct.id = c.Id and ct.Location = 'Country'
where c.Location = 'City'
```

Not very difficult :(

Comment: Actually I disagree. That's a general implementation and as as long as the table has an index on ID it will be efficient. I use Pivots a lot and it never occurred to me to use one.

Comment: Fair enough. It IS cumbersome, but performance should be OK. If you make some kind of edit, I'll give you your point back. Note that the index will likely be on (id,location)

Comment: And, thinking about it, it has the advantage that a view constructed this way would be editable!